# How to prevent Large Title from Collapsing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

The question is simple, how can I prevent a Large Title Navigation Bar from collapse when a scrollview scrolls down?

My navigation must have a large navigation bar at all times... so when a scrollview scroll, the navigation bar shouldn't collapse up, it should stay the same size, how can I do that?

This is how I set the largeTitle preferences

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    presenter.expandForSimulatorLayoutIfNeeded()

}


func expandForSimulatorLayoutIfNeeded(){
            if !isExpanded{
        topMenu = TopMenu(frame: expandedNavigationFrame, interactor: interactor)
        oldNavigationBarFrame = navigationBar.frame
        self.navigationBar.addSubview(topMenu)
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    } else {
        self.navigationBar.frame = expandedNavigationFrame
    }

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topMenu, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topMenu, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topMenu, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.navigationBar, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topMenu, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: navigationBar, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    topMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, widthConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

}
```

Answer (score 20):

A workaround i figured out is to add a placeholder view that is not `CollectionView/TableView` as the very first view in `ViewController's` base view. This first view will be attached to the top of the safeArea, height can be zero.

**Using Storyboard/Xib:**

See the below screenshot for this view with constraints

[image]

Next add another `UIView` to serve as a container view for your `TableView/CollectionView`. This container's top will be attached to bottom of the placeholder view. See the below screenshot for constraints of container view and `TableView/CollectionView`.

[image]

The key here is the first view in the view hierarchy as the `navigation bar` will check that to set the collapsing effect. Once it does not find it as a `CollectionView/TableView`, it will not collapse on scrolling.

**Programmatically:**

If you are setting up view's programmatically then you just need to add a placeholder view at the top.

e.g,

```
self.view.addSubview(UIView(frame: .zero))
self.view.addSubview(tableView) // or collectionView
```

Answer (score 7):

If someone arrives here from SwiftUI land, this is a good way to keep your lists in large title mode.

```
// your content view ...

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PreventCollapseView()
            List {
                ForEach(things, id: \.self) { thing in
                    Text(thing.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("All the things")
    }


// end of view


struct PreventCollapseView: View {

    private var mostlyClear = Color(UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.0005))

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(mostlyClear)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I set `VStack(spacing; 0)` to get the content as close to the `PreventCollapseView` as possible.

Comment: unfortunately this causes the row to remain highlighted after navigating back if using navigation links in your list.  Known iOS bug before iOS 15. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934037/swiftui-navigationlink-cell-in-a-form-stays-highlighted-after-detail-pop

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the large tile nav bar from collapsing simply add a second view to your UIViewController in the viewDidLoad method.

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
```

For whatever reason, this breaks the link between your the UIScrollView and the nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you created other views on storyboard, then just call below method on `viewDidLoad`.

```
private func preventLargeTitleCollapsing() {
    let dummyView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(dummyView)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(dummyView)
}
```

My original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66504612/4061501).