# How to deselect a list button within a NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a list with one of the list items in a NavigationLink because it needs to move to a detail view once tapped. When I come back from that detail view the list button is still in a selected state. Prior to SwiftUI, I'd just tell the .isSelected to equal false but I can't figure out how to do that in SwiftUI?

```
List {
      NavigationLink(destination: SettingsStartdayView()){
          HStack {
             Text("Start Day Notification")
             Spacer()
             Text(startDayNotificationSetting)
                 .font(.subheadline)
                 .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                 .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
          }
     }
}
```

| Starting List View | After Detail View, Back |
| --- | --- |
| [image: First] | [image: row] |

This View is being loaded into the main app's view through:

```
NavigationView{
            TabView(selection: $isSelectedTab) {
                 SettingsView()
                   .tabItem{
                   }.tag(1)
```

Here's a public project that has a complete example of what I'm dealing with: https://gitlab.com/jammyman34/test-sounds-project

Go to the Settings tab and then click the top list item to go to the detail page. Notice how the list you clicked stays selected when you go back. It doesn't clear unless you change to the other tab.

Comment: Can you show the full hierarchy up to the root `NavigationView`?

Comment: I edited the description to hopefully answer your question. Was that what you were asking @pawello2222

Comment: Yes, but I see that's not enough in this case. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @pawello2222 does this help https://gitlab.com/jammyman34/test-sounds-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the `Text` which is above the `List` in SettingsView - a bug reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63997371/8697793).

Instead, you can use a *native* navigation title and attach it to the TabView.

```
struct SettingsHomeView: View {
    
    @State var startDayNotificationSetting: String = "8:30AM"
    @State var appVersion: String = "0.01"
    
    var body: some View {
        // no `Text` above `List`
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: SettingsStartdayView()){
                HStack {
                    Text("Start Day Notification")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(startDayNotificationSetting)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    //Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isSelectedTab = 1 // select the first tab
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            TabView(selection: $isSelectedTab) {
                // ...
            }
            // control displaying the title depending on the `isSelectedTab`
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
            .navigationBarHidden(isSelectedTab == 1)
        }
    }
}
```