# How to make SwiftUI navigation Bar display large titles ALWAYS

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, preferslargetitles

I want to have a navigation bar display large titles always.  i.e., not to make the title small in a scroll view when the scrolling.

I believe previously we would achieve this typing

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

What is the equivalent way of doing this in swiftUI?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/58870842/10883380

Comment: Actually the problem with this approach is that if your using navigaitonlinks in your list the list row remains highlighted when popping back.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934037/swiftui-navigationlink-cell-in-a-form-stays-highlighted-after-detail-pop